# How do I get attached properties to work in code-behind

Tags: wpf, code-behind, attached-properties

I'm trying to get attached properties to work in code behind, but I'm clearly missing something. As I understand it result should be "test", but it is string.Empty.

The LogicalTreeHelper states that `child` is the child of `parent`, so the tree is set up correctly.

Any suggestions?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var parent = new TestParent();
        var child = new Child();
        parent.AddLogicalChild(child);
        parent.SetValue(TestParent.TestProperty, "test");

        var result = child.GetValue(TestParent.TestProperty); // Returns ""

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


class TestParent : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(string), typeof(TestParent), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public void AddLogicalChild(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        base.AddLogicalChild(element);
    }
}

class Child : FrameworkElement
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a logical tree like this doesn't work. You can easily check that by looking at the parent's [`LogicalChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.logicalchildren.aspx) property after calling AddLogicalChild. It is still `null`. You may want to look into [How to: Override the Logical Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742244.aspx).

However, your inheriting property works well:

```
var parent = new StackPanel();
var child = new TextBlock();
parent.Children.Add(child);
parent.SetValue(TestParent.TestProperty, "test");

var result = child.GetValue(TestParent.TestProperty); // returns "test"
```